# how to use pig script to insert newline character into the content

Tags: apache-pig

Here is the data

123,456,789,q,w,e,r,20120513

123,77,88,8,jj,oo,"ooo,\r\n""d,\r\ndf,123",20120514

123,77,88,8,jj,oo,ooo,20120514

I want replace these \r\n to newline character by using pig script.

```
Pig Script:

    REGISTER file:///usr/share/pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;

    DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader;

    RAW = LOAD '/home/bannie/test/test.log' 
            USING CSVLoader()  AS (
                a: chararray, 
                b: chararray, 
                c: chararray, 
                d: chararray, 
                e: chararray, 
                f: chararray, 
                g: chararray, 
                h: chararray
            );

    C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REPLACE(g, '\\\\r\\\\n', '\uxxxx') as max;

grunt> C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REPLACE(g, '\\\\r\\\\n', '\u000f') as max;
    grunt> C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REPLACE(g, '\\\\r\\\\n', '\u000e') as max;
    grunt> C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REPLACE(g, '\\\\r\\\\n', '\u000d') as max;
    2013-06-03 17:53:42,629 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 55, column 32>  mismatched input '(' expecting SEMI_COLON
    Details at logfile: /home/bannie/pig_1370249955149.log
    grunt> C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REPLACE(g, '\\\\r\\\\n', '\u000a') as max;
    2013-06-03 17:53:47,601 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 55, column 32>  mismatched input '(' expecting SEMI_COLON
    Details at logfile: /home/bannie/pig_1370249955149.log
    grunt> C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REPLACE(g, '\\\\r\\\\n', '\u000b') as max;
    grunt> C = FOREACH RAW GENERATE REPLACE(g, '\\\\r\\\\n', '\u000c') as max;

Anyone knows how to insert it?
```

Comment: Already solved, by using REPLACE(f6, '\\\\n', '\n') as f6 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert anything to a file. Pig has the same limitation of Hadoop Map Reduce. By default, the output is a directory containing some part-*-* files.